# Condition in select statement where based same on the Condition

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am new to MSSQL. i need to change the condition in select statement where based same on the Condition.
I try to store the where clause Conditions in One variable and assign that variable in into the select statement where clause.

Like This..

```
declare @test varchar(max);
declare @test1 varchar(max);
set @test=' id = 14';
select FirstName from tblUser where @test;
```

But it so some error.

Like:

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.
```

Please tell me any other way implement this flow...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using dynamic SQL. For more information see link from Obed's answer

```
    declare @test nvarchar(max);
    create table tblUser (id int, FirstName varchar(10))
    set @test=N' id = 14';
    set @test=N'select FirstName from tblUser where '+@test
    exec sp_executesql @test;

    drop table tblUser
```

Comment: I think, no. Maybe, someone else will offer you better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store whole conditions in variables for execution, in particular if they contain column names.

You can do this if you are going to use dynamic SQL, but that comes with it's own set of complications. [This](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) article is good reading about dynamic SQL (The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL).

I would question your need to do so, however.